# Java android Index out of Bound exception on Click event

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am having an issue with an Onclick event that keeps giving me an Out Of Bounds Exception . I basically have a list of car names about 30 of them on the list, when someone clicks a car name a checkmark appears next to it . When someone clicks it again I make the checkmark dissapear and that is usually when I get an out of bounds exceptions .. this is my code

```
 private ArrayList<Integer> selected_positions= new ArrayList<>();
 binding.list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {


                      if(selected_positions.contains(position)) {
                          // Position is already CheckMarked so remove
                          selected_positions.remove(position);
                      }   else  {
                          // Position Clicked for the 1st time
                       selected_positions.add(position);
                   }



            final FilterCarsAdapter FS = new FilterCarsAdapter(getActivity(),  binding,selected_positions);
            binding.list.setAdapter(FS);


        }
    });
```

I am basically holding the values that are clicked inside the **Selected_Positions** ArrayList by Position . The issue is for instance clicks always work, if I click the item in index 2 then the checkmark appears but if I click it again to remove it I get **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 1** and if I position 5 then i get **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 1** . Any help would be great as I am new to Java .

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that when u use `selected_positions.remove(position);` it's trying to find and remove Integer at `position` position number.

you need: `selected_positions.remove((Integer)position);`

Comment: Thanks a lot that is exactly what was needed .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you handle the multi_touch. In the case of lower memory devices the click event can be so slow that you click next item. So throws that Exception

You need to check this condition:

```
if(selected_positions.size()>position){
    selected_positions.remove(position);
}
```